# How to disable vertical scrolling without e.preventdefault()

Tags: jquery, html, webview, scroll, zooming

I'm doing an app in Titanium. In this application, I have to load some graphs so I use a webview.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/zGTjJ/) is the html I'm loading.

In the application I want to zoom some parts of the app so I put all content inside a scroll view:

```
var view = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    height : utils.getScreenHeight(),
    width : utils.getScreenWidth(),
    backgroundColor : "#393a3a",
    maxZoomScale : 100,
    minZoomScale : 1,
    //With this property you can set the default zoom
    zoomScale : 1
});
```

It works ok, I can zoom the view and the webview. However, the webview allow vertical scrolled and it interfere with zoom. I mean, if you try to zoom inside the webview, sometimes zoom is applied and sometimes the webview is vertically scrolled.

I've tried to disable vertical scroll, but the only way I've found to get it works is this:

```
    document.ontouchmove = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    };
```

But if I put this, zoom doesn't work.

I've tried also with:

```
        body {
            overflow-y:hidden;
        }
```

But it doesn't work.

Do you know if there is any other way to disable vertical scroll? 
Why the view is scrolling vertically if content is small than their container?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I've tried it, but zoom doesn't work...

Comment: Using the CSS tyle `body,html{scroll: hidden;}` ?